# Concurrent Story Reporters in Jbehave

Tags: java, selenium, jbehave

I am developing my custom story reporter which extends NullStoryReporter. But my tests should be run in concurrent mode. For this case I found ConcurrentStoryReporter in `org.jbehave.core.reporters` package, but I have some difficulties in its usage.

ConcurrentStoryReporter' constructor:

```
public ConcurrentStoryReporter(StoryReporter crossReferencing, StoryReporter delegate, boolean multiThreading) {
    this.crossReferencing = crossReferencing;
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.multiThreading = multiThreading;
    delayedMethods = multiThreading ? Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<DelayedMethod>()) : null;
}
```

As I understand the delegate is my custom story reporter. But could you, please, clarify what should I cast as 'StoryReporter crossReferencing' to the constructor? Are there any example of usage the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`crossReferencing` could be `new NullStoryReporter()`.

In general it's not required to use `ConcurrentStoryReporter` explicitly. JBehave [wraps reporters automatically](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/reporters/StoryReporterBuilder.java#L365) when number of [threads is more than 1](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/embedder/Embedder.java#L453).

Comment: Yeah, I agree `NullStoryReporter` could be a `crossReferencing`, but it is quit strange to transmit redundant object to the reporter' constructor as well as `boolean multiThreading`.  All that is needed here is `StoryReporter delegate`. It is just my thoughts... Thank you so much for your answer, bro!